# Custom handler for Rails 401 authentication errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I've got an API controller where it's important that all error responses get returned as JSON.

The following setup handles errors raised from actions, but not the authentication error raised in the before filter- it throws a 401 that rails sends out as text/html.

```
  class ApiController < ActionController::Base

    rescue_from StandardError, with: :handle_errors
    before_filter :restrict_access

    def restrict_access
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        false # Force authentication error
      end
    end

    def handle_errors(exception)
      render :json => { :errors => { :error => exception.message} }.to_json, :status => 400
    end
```

What do I need to do to handle the authentication error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method below is being called when access is denied.

```
def Token.authentication_request(controller, realm)
  controller.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
  controller.__send__ :render, :text => "HTTP Token: Access denied.\n", :status => :unauthorized
end
```

You could try and override it to change the behavior like:

```
def Token.authentication_request(controller, realm)
  controller.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
  controller.__send__ :render, :json => { :errors => { :error => exception.message} }.to_json, :status => 400
end
```

Comment: @Gjaldon- Thanks, this got me there, though I found it easier to override the request_http_token_authentication controller method instead of monkey patching - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20763274/165673).

Comment: Cool then! I'm glad my answer was of help. :)

Answer (score 4):

After @Gjaldon's answer helped me figure it out, I ended up overriding [request_http_token_authentication](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb) in my API controller:

```
def request_http_token_authentication(realm = "Application")  
  self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
  self.__send__ :render, :json => { :error => "HTTP Token: Access denied. You did not provide an valid API key." }.to_json, :status => :unauthorized
end
```

Comment: Hate to do the same, but could not figure out anything smarter.